# No server to serve request. Check logs for details

Tags: android

I tried uninstalling Android studio multiple times but still get the error below when I build the project

> Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for
> details.
>
> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
>
> Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: No server to serve request. Check logs for details.
> Not what sure is causing these errors